# How to detect if the right arrow is pressed in an if statement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a new programmer trying to make a game in Unity and I want to make an if statement that senses when the right arrow key is pressed.
This has been working for me so far with letter keys:

```
if (Input.GetKey("d")) {
   //Code would be here
}
```

I've looked, but I can't find anything that can replace the letter string so it senses the pressing of the right arrow button.

Comment: It's all in the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.UpArrow.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of Enum KeyCode.
What you need is `KeyCode.RightArrow`.

You can see it in [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.RightArrow.html) and also in the [.NET API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Keys_KeyCode)

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried this before and it failed, but I tried it again just now and found another problem that was really small yet codebreaking, that was pointing errors toward the key input.

Comment: @Amethyst That is one of the reasons why is very important creating a [mcve] of the problem. While doing it you can rule out what you are commenting it happened to you

Comment: @Cleptus +1 for your comment. I have found issues several times that, in the process of creating a [mcve] for a question, found that I can't reproduce, and that has led me to the solution (or at least given me more information about where the problem lies).

Comment: @Cleptus _"That is one of the reasons why is very important creating a minimal reproducible example of the problem"_ - generally the correct response to that is _"**that's a new question...feel free to post a new one**"_.  The OPs supplied code was more than sufficient for the title

Comment: @MickyD Indeed, but in a comment in this answer OP said their problem was somewhere else yet the error message was pointing to that code, so the the advice to create a separate project to reproduce the problem I believe is relevant. I have **not** downvoted nor flagged this question.

Comment: @Cleptus we're kinda on the same page but the question is about _"How to detect if the right arrow is pressed in an if statement?"_ not say _Compiler Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable yourGuessIsAsGoodAsMineAsToWhatOPisDoing_. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out bellow code for a right arrow key pressed detection. Put this code in `Update()`

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    Debug.Log("right Arrow key pressed");
}
```

If you want to use other arrows, then use `KeyCode.LeftArrow`, `KeyCode.UpArrow`, `KeyCode.DownArrow`

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add a little bit more information:

You can get three type of events on key pressed.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    print("right Arrow key pressed");
}

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    print("right Arrow was released");
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
   print("right Arrow is held down");
}
```